# X won't start unless I do Ctrl-C about three times after running startx

Tags: xorg, mint

Partial demonstration with `ttyrec`/`ttyplay`: https://www.sendspace.com/file/low2h7

I am currently using a `.xsession` of:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec i3 --force-xinerama >>~/.i3/log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting log file:

```
rm ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log
```

After that, no more doing `Ctrl+C` to make it start.